# Debug display multidimensional arrays in user-friendly format

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, debugging, multidimensional-array

I have a specific signature of two-dimension array in C#:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Neurons array
/// <para>[0,:] == Neuron id</para>
/// <para>[1,:] == Type (1 - input, 2 - output, 3 - hidden)</para>
/// <para>[2,:] == Activation function</para>
/// </summary>
public int[,] Neurons { get; private set; }
```

So, if I'll look on this property through Visual Studio I'll see something like:
[image: default multi-dimention debug display]

I want to display this property in user-friendly format. Something like this:
[image: user-friendly multi0dimention debug display]

Can I achieve that behaviour? And how?

*P.S. Final goal is to make debug multi-dimensions arrays more easy.*

Comment: You can use List of custom types like this: `List<Neuron>`

Comment: @Hadi, thank you for your response, but I need to use multi-dimensional array for performance reason

Comment: So where is the usage of user-friendly format??

Comment: @Hadi, the question about display multi-dimensions arrays in user-friendly mode in such specific case. Not about how to make user-friendly structures to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is a little bit troublesome but if you think it will make things easier it worth . The solution depends on creating `DebuggerView` and a `DebuggerTypeProxy`. We will use proxy to format our data. And DebuggerView to display formatted data.

```
        [DebuggerDisplay("Id:{Id} | Type:{Type} | Act:{Act}")] // format properties as you like
        public class TypeContainer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public int Type { get; set; }

            public int Act { get; set; }
        }

        [DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
        [DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(FakeNeuronDebugView))] // specify a proxy 
        public class MyFakeNeuron
        {

            public MyFakeNeuron()
            {
                this.Neurons = new int[10, 10];
            }

            public int[,] Neurons { get; set; }

            private string DebuggerDisplay => "Count = " + this.Neurons.Length;

            private class FakeNeuronDebugView
            {
                private readonly MyFakeNeuron myFakeNeuron;
                public FakeNeuronDebugView(MyFakeNeuron myFakeNeuron)
                {
                    this.myFakeNeuron = myFakeNeuron;
                }

                [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
                public TypeContainer[] Values
                {
                    get
                    {
                        var keys = new List<TypeContainer>();
                        var source = this.myFakeNeuron.Neurons;
                        for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(0); j++)
                        {
                            var key = new TypeContainer
                            {
                                Id = source[0, j],
                                Type = source[1, j],
                                Act = source[2, j],
                            };
                            keys.Add(key);
                        }

                        return keys.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

For further reading :[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Definately what I need. This is a little complex solution, but it's such flexible. Thank you, @Eldar

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio Extensions to improve the experience you gather with arrays. [Array Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmirLiberman.ArrayVisualizer)

Comment: Unfortunately, this extension works with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 only.
No support for VS 2017 or 2019. Can't see free extensions for latest VS version right now in marketplace.

Comment: I guess noone's just tested yet, always worth trying.

Comment: Tried to install it right now. Vsix installer throws error on latest VS 2019 (16.4.0).